# Create a list of random numbers with sum = n

Tags: beginner, vba, random, excel

I want to create a list of random integers in the range [0, 9], that sums up to 100 in Excel, using VBA. The list should be printed in a single column.

The routine I've written is as follows:

```vbs
Sub RandomList()
    Dim arr(100) As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    i = 0
    Do
        arr(i) = Int(10 * Rnd())
        i = i + 1
    Loop Until WorksheetFunction.Sum(arr) >= 100

    arr(i - 1) = 100 - WorksheetFunction.Sum(arr) + arr(i - 1)
    Range("A1").Resize(i, 1) = Application.Transpose(arr)

End Sub
```

This gives the correct result, but I'm sure there are ways to improve it:

- Initializing the size to 100, seems odd. I want to use a [dynamic sized array](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/dynamic-array.html), but I can't get it to work. I've tried different approaches, but all result in a list containing only zeros (or an error).
- I tried to sum all elements except the last one, but I didn't manage to make it work. Therefore I had to sum all elements, and subtract the last one. I can't believe that's optimal.
- Should I delete the `(100-i)` last elements of the list somehow, before writing it to Excel? How and why?
- Is the last line a good way of writing to Excel, or is there a better way?
- I'm looking for a nice and clean way of doing this task, not necessarily the fastest way

I can do the same thing using `Function RandomList()` too, but as far as I can tell, that's used when I want to call the function from the worksheet.

PS! I'm not interested in some builtin function that can do the task directly, as I'm doing this to learn VBA, not to do that specific task.

---

This is inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37835877/2338750) (bad) question on SO. There are other approaches there that can be used, but they are substantially different. I'm wondering if the way I'm doing this is a "good way" of doing it, or if it's filled with "Bad practice" code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Your logic is hacky, and your array should be dynamic.**
**Then, you should generalise your function so it can be used in other circumstances.**

---

**Also, Logic Error:**

You've *assumed* that you won't need more elements than your target sum. But what if `Rnd()` returns 100 zeroes? You'll get to `i = 101`, try to set the value of `arr(101)` and error because you only sized it for 100 elements. Hence why you need a dynamic array.

---

**Dynamic array:**

```
Dim dynamicArray () As Integer
ReDim dynamicArray (1 to 1)

Dim i As Long
For i = 1 to 100
    ReDim Preserve dynamicArray (1 to i)
Next i
```

`Redim Preserve` extends the dimension whilst preserving all the values already in it. It only works on the last dimension so if, for instance, you had a 2-D Array, you could only `Redim Preserve` the 2nd Dimension.

---

**Better Logic:**

Start a counter at 100 (call it `remainder`)
Add random Int from 0-9 to list
Remove Int from counter
Do until counter <= 0
Reduce the last Int by the negative amount now held by remainder

Like so:

```
Dim sumList() As Long
ReDim sumList(1 To 1)

Dim remainder As Long
remainder = 100

Dim i As Long
Dim rndNum As Double
Do Until remainder <= 0
    i = i + 1
    ReDim Preserve sumList(1 To i)
    rndNum = WorksheetFunction.Floor(10 * Rnd(), 0)
    sumList(i) = rndNum
    remainder = remainder - rndNum
Loop
sumList(i) = sumList(i) + remainder
```

---

**Refactoring/Generalising:**

Your sub is very specific (0-9, sum of 100, integers). Why not make it a function that accepts these things as parameters? Then, whenever you need any kind of random list, you can just call your function with whatever parameters 
you need without writing a new one.

Parameters:

- Allowed Value Range (2 parameters. A `minValue` and a `maxValue`)
- `targetSum`
- (Optional) level of precision (integers (0 DP), 1 Decimal Place, 2 etc.)

---

**Mathematical Note:**

Allowing for any value space (say, numbers from 2.7 to 3.81 with values of 3 decimal places):

First, compute the size of the space (max - min). For a range of 2 to 7, the size would be 7-2 = 5.
We then add an extra buffer so that `Floor()` has an equal chance of hitting the top of our value space. This will be `1 * 10 ^ (-numDecimalPlaces)`.
We then multiply `Rnd()` by the size of the space to get a random position **within** our value space.
Then add that value to our `minValue`, and `Floor()` to the appropriate level of precision.

---

**Function:**

```
Public Function RandList(ByVal minValue As Double, ByVal maxValue As Double, ByVal targetSum As Double, Optional ByVal numDecimalPlaces As Long = 0) As Double()

    sumTotal = WorksheetFunction.Floor(sumTotal, numDecimalPlaces) '/ In Case, e.g. the total is 100.24 but we're only working in whole numbers

    Dim sumList() As Double
    ReDim sumList(1 To 1)

    Dim remainder As Double
    remainder = targetSum

    Dim valueSpace As Double
    valueSpace = maxValue - minValue + 1 * 10 ^ (-numDecimalPlaces) '/ 1 * 10 ^ (-numDecimalPlaces) is our Floor() buffer so we can still hit the top of the value space.

    Dim i As Long
    Dim rndNum As Double
    Do Until remainder <= 0
        i = i + 1
        ReDim Preserve sumList(1 To i)
        rndNum = WorksheetFunction.Floor(minValue + (Rnd() * valueSpace), numDecimalPlaces)
        sumList(i) = rndNum
        remainder = remainder - rndNum
    Loop
    sumList(i) = sumList(i) + remainder


    RandList = sumList

End Function
```

---

Which you can then call like so:

```
Public Sub DescriptiveName()

    Dim sumList() As Double
    sumList = RandList(0, 9, 100)

    '/ Stuff to print sumList goes here

End Sub
```

---

**N.B.** Thanks to [@arcadeprecinct](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/106849/arcadeprecinct) and [@raystafarian](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/75587/raystafarian) for suggestions and improvements.

Comment: Wouldn't `sumList(i) = sumList(i) + remainder` have the same effect as the second half of the function?

Comment: You know, it would ^^

Comment: Wait, why is this a function?

Comment: @Raystafarian Oh, yeah, whoops. I should put the return statement in.

Comment: Ah I was trying to figure out if it was somehow faster to do (few) increments/decrements instead of an addition^^ Kinda like "it's faster to check `>=0` so let's loop backwards". As long as we're at it: You don't need the `lastIndex` variable because `i` has still that value. I'm not sure about the exact probability but I feel that `remainder = 0` is a pretty unlikely outcome so it'd be possible to drop that check too.

Comment: @arcadeprecinct You're right. We can just add the remainder and if it's 0 then it'll just have no effect.

Comment: Would the function be declared as a variant or would (could?) it be declared as something else?

Comment: @Raystafarian Oh, yeah, that too ^^ you just declare it as `Function() As Double()`

Comment: Thanks! This is great! =) For the record (in my defense): It wasn't really a logical flaw, it was based on probability. The likelihood of getting to 101 elements is extremely low, but you are right... It _could_ happen, especially since the numbers `[0,9], n=100` can change.

Comment: @hobbs Not quite. The way the logic is constructed, it's impossible that the final value (after adjustment) will fall outside the value range. It's true that if the average value of the random number is negative, and the target is positive, then it could potentially run forever, but IMO that's not a problem that it should seek to solve.

Comment: @hobbs also, stopping as soon as we get to `maxvalue` is not, necessarily, the desired behaviour. Imagine a range from 1-5, where we get to a remainder of 4. We could just return 4 and be done with it, but the RNG might well give us 4 1's if we allow it to continue.

Answer (score 6):

The procedure is doing a number of completely unrelated things that should be separated:

- Populating an array with random integers
- Dumping an array of random integers onto a worksheet

Make the procedure a `Function`, and rename it to something that starts with a verb, something that *tells the reader what it does*. `GenerateRandomValues` for example.

I'd take the magic cap-value `100` as a (perhaps `Optional`) parameter.

Every time you use `WorksheetFunction.Sum`, you're making Excel iterate all values in the array, add up all the values and return a value *that you should already know*.

Declare a local variable to hold the cumulative sum, and add every new generated integer to it as you add it to the array: then when you need to know what the total is, *you don't need to calculate or iterate anything*, it's right there waiting to be used.

Make the function return the array, and then make another procedure responsible for calling that function, and consuming its result: then you can write as many test methods (in a dedicated test module) as you like, to document your specifications and programmatically validate that the function works as intended given any input!

I'd rename `arr` to either `result` or `values`.

---

> *Initializing the size to 100, seems odd. I want to use a dynamic sized array*

Indeed. See [@Zak's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/132081/23788), but then I'd make sure to minimize the amount of resizing happening, and initialize the dynamic array with 11 items, since it's a given that you're going to need *at least* that many iterations to get to a sum of 100 if you're generating random numbers between 0 and 9. This could be calculated if the 100 is a parameter.

> *Is the last line a good way of writing to Excel, or is there a better way?*

You're dumping an entire array of values in a single write, it doesn't get any better than that! If transposing the output makes it look the way it needs to be, then having Excel to the hard work of transposing the values is the best way to go about it IMO. The only problem I'm seeing is that you're implicitly referring to the active sheet, which may or may not be where you want to dump the results: it's always best to use an explicit worksheet reference, rather than `[_Global].Range()`.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's pretty good. An alternate way of handling some of that would be

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub RandomList()
    Columns(1).Clear
    Dim myNumbers(100) As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim k as Long
    i = 0
    k = 0
    Do
        j = Int(10 * Rnd())
        'If j = 0 Then j = 1 optional if you want to keep 0s
        If k + j > 100 Then j = 100 - k
        k = k + j
        myNumbers(i) = j
        i = i + 1
    Loop Until k = 100
    Range("A1").Resize(i, 1) = Application.Transpose(myNumbers)
End Sub
```

It's just eliminating `0`s and fixing the last element before exiting the loop.

---

Actually, since you're looking for *n* I might do this

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub RandomList()
    Const mySum = 100
    Columns(1).Clear
    Dim myNumbers(mySum) As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim k As Long
    i = 0
    k = 0
    Do
        j = Int(10 * Rnd())
        'If j = 0 Then j = 1 optional if you want to keep 0s
        If k + j > mySum Then j = mySum - k
        k = k + j
        myNumbers(i) = j
        i = i + 1
    Loop Until k = mySum
    Range("A1").Resize(i, 1) = Application.Transpose(myNumbers)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

After generating the random values, you should shuffle them once. Otherwise the last elements will on average be smaller than 4.5, the expected average.

Comment: Good point, one of the numbers won't be truly random. Depending on what the list is for it's probably good enough, but if it's for something "important" like cryptography or gambling, I guess it's possible it matters :)